# jQuery children method selecting grandchildren

Tags: jquery, children

I was following tutorial on net.tuts on jQuery. I am having problem with jQuery children selection method. My understanding with the following function I could change color of the children but it goes more than one level down to change color of all list elements to red. What did I do wrong? I have seen the same script work fine on the video tutorial. Here is the code

```
<ul class="color_change">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li> 
        <ul>
            <li>sub item</li>
            <li>sub item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    $('ul.color_change').children('li').css('color','red');
</script>`
```

Comment: This is because CSS color is inherited from its parent

Comment: roasted is absolute correct. Put a css to color your li (other then red)
Check this fiddle.. [http://jsfiddle.net/Z9BC6/]
dont get confused !

Comment: your fiddle doesnt work, but I gave one point since you pointed out what I missed from the tutorial I was following, that is setting a base color.

Answer (score 5):

You could use that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9BC6/)

```
$('ul.color_change').children('li').not(':has(ul)').css('color','red');
```

An other way which will set red color for all first level children:

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9BC6/1/)

```
$('ul.color_change').find('ul').css('color','black').end().children('li').css('color','red');
```

But better would be to just use CSS rules:

[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9BC6/1/)

```
ul.color_change > li{color:red}
ul.color_change > li > ul{color:black}
```

Comment: I have given you one point for taking your time and explaining different methods. Finally, I looked the tutorial again, and you are right "css color inherited from its parent". I forgot one point from the tutorial, that is adding a base color li{color:black}; it would solve the issue. Thanks